# adjective for longing/yearning?

Tags: single-word-requests

Not necessarily from those specific words, something that conveys an accurate meaning.

For example, an adjective like:
'Longing' messages.

Comment: What's wrong with [***yearnful**?*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Yearnful)

Answer (score 1):

> [**urgent**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/urgent) *adjective*:
>
> **1a**: calling for immediate attention : pressing
>
> **1b**: conveying a sense of urgency. (Merriam-Webster *online*)

Answer (score 0):

**ardent** (*adj.*):

very enthusiastic or passionate

**impassioned** (*adj.*):

filled with or showing great emotion

**longing** (*adj.*):

having or showing a yearning desire

**lovesick** (*adj.*):

in love, or missing the person one loves, so much that one is unable to act normally

**wistful** (*adj.*):

having or showing a feeling of vague or regretful longing

Source: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com)